# How do I bring parent window in front of child modeless dialog when parent window clicked

Tags: wpf

Currently from my application I'm firing off a modeless window.  This new window will show on top of the main application.  I would like to give my users the ability to just click on the main application which is just behind the popup and bring it to the front.  Right now the user would have to minimize the popup to access the main application.  Here is what I'm essentially doing:

```
    Window dialog = new Window
    {

        Content = new Control(data),
        Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow,
        ShowInTaskbar = true,
        WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner
    };

dialog.Show();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take out this line:

```
Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow
```

and you should get the behavior you want.  By specifying the owner window you are keeping the child window always in front.

Comment: That answers my question. But my new issue is this line won't work "WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner" because it no longer has an owner.

Comment: In order to still allow my pop up window to center on the parent window, I had to keep everything the same, but when the child control was fully loaded I added this block of code to remove the owner: Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
parentWindow.Owner = null;